Fourier transform of low decay functions
Let $s(u)$ a non-negative function on $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $|s(u)-s(0)|\leqslant c|u|^a$ in the neighbourhood of $0$, for some $a>0$. We also assume that $|s(u)|\leq c\|u\|^p$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ for some $p>0$,  so that $s$ is tempered, and can consider its Fourier transform $C$ in the space of distributions.
We know that if $C$ is a sufficiently integrable function, then this holds for $a=1$. Is it possible in the other direction to deduce something on $C$ by assuming that it holds for some $a$?
For instance, if it holds for $a=1$, does it mean that $C$ is integrable? If the answer is negative, what if we assume that the dimension is $d=1$?
